# IBM websphere application server is giving me a null value from getinitparameter() and I cant figure out why

Tags: java, web, websphere, servletcontextlistener

I have been tasked at work with fixing some other teams deployment into IBM Websphere

They use javax servletcontext to get values out of web.xml

I have read so many articles

sc is ServletContext passed in as a parameter

( I'm new to IBM websphere )

```
     Enumeration<String> testParam = sc.getInitParameterNames();

    while(testParam.hasMoreElements()) {


        String value = testParam.nextElement();
        sc.getInitParameter(value);
        
        
    }
```

but I can do anything to web.xml and it sees no changes

I have tried adding

```
 <Context-param>
```

and i have tried adding

```
 <init-param>
```

and then searching by that param name directly which returns a null

also I have queried all the params using the pasted code example and it shows none of my test params

yet
also it has found a param by the name of "WELD_CONTEXT_ID_KEY" which translates to the value of the war but I used

Findstr /s /i "WELD_CONTEXT_ID_KEY" *.*

at the server root and that string only exists in the log from the code I created

I Have no idea what to do because I cant seem to affect change and I cant find that param name

PLEASE HELP***

Comment: You tried adding `<init-param>` how? There are a lot of case errors in this post. More care required.

Comment: From what I read on the internet the init parameter goes inside the servlet tag and the servlet name  comes from the class that extends the servlet however the class that accepts the parameter sc that calls getinitparam is not a servlet so that I don’t have an  answer for yet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone who comes across this problem in the future

I learned that the solution is to fix the web_merged.xml inside a different folder

as it turns out
Websphere takes the war and creates multiple iterations it looks like

leaving web.xml inside

[server name 1]\profiles[server name]\config\cells[cell name]\applications[\deployments\[application war]\[application war]\WEB-INF\

there you can find web_merged.xml
web.xml

and then you can find a copy of web.xml
inside

[server name 1]\profiles[server name 1]\installedApps[cell name][application war][application war]\WEB-INF\